# How can I put an HTML tag inside a <label> in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How can I put a `<span>` tag inside an `f.label` tag?

```
<%= f.label :test %>
```

Requested output:

```
<label for="test">test<span>*</span></label>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to tell rails that the string you're giving it does not need to be sanitized. Use `String#html_safe`.

```
<%= f.label :test, "test<span>*</span>".html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 20):

Label accepts a block, so you can do this:

```
<%= f.label :test do %>
   <span>*</span>
<%end%>
```

Comment: this is the best way

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<%= f.label :test, 'test<span>*</span>'.html_safe %>
```

Comment: you'll get escaped output this way: `<input for="test">test&lt;span&gt;*&lt;/span&gt;</input>`